# How to determine version of http in get html?

Tags: html, get

I want to request a server by 'get' and I use this method:

http://smarttracking.ir/gprmc_receiver.php?strVar=27,0,146,1,$GPRMC,213659.000,A,3238.0007,N,05118.5837,E,36.74,274.01,170114,,,N*6A5,username1,64,5}

If you copy this in the address bar on your browser, you will get a response. But there is a problem for me. I send this by sim900 module and it doesn't support http 1.0 or 1.1 and it is less than 1 so I need to send http version by address bar if it is possible. Something like this:

http://smarttracking.ir/gprmc_receiver.php?id=1 http/1.1 strVar=27,0,146,1,$GPRMC,213659.000,A,3238.0007,N,05118.5837,E,36.74,274.01,170114,,,N*6A5,username1,64,5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a socket from the sim900 module to  http://smarttraking.it and send a http request in according to the standard. The format of http request offers the possibility to specify the http version.

Look this image:
[format http request](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~shankar/417-F01/Slides/chapter2a-aus/img016.gif)